# Julia AffineTransforms sign of rotation angle

Tags: rotation, julia, affinetransform

I am using AffineTransforms to rotate a volume. I am confused now by the sign of the rotation angle. For a right-hand system, when looking down an axis, say Z axis, rotating the XY plane counter-clockwise should be positive angles. I define a rotation matrix `r = [0.0 -1. 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 1.0]`, which is to rotate along the Z axis 90 degree counter-clockwise. Indeed, `r * [1 0 0]'` gives [`0 1 0]'`, which rotates X axis to Y axis.

Now I define a volume v.

```
3×3×3 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 3] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

then I define `tfm = AffineTransform(r, vec([0 0 0])))` which is the same as `tfm = tformrotate(vec([0 0 1]), π/2)`.
then `transform(v, tfm)`. The rotation center is the input array center. I got

```
3×3×3 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 3] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

This is surprising to me because the output is the 90 degree rotation along Z axis but clockwise. It seems to me that this is actually a -90 degree rotation. Could somebody point out what I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admittedly, this confused me too. Had to read the help for `transform` and `TransformedArray` again.

First, the print order of arrays is a bit confusing, with the first index shown in columns, but it is the X-axis, as the dimensions of `v` are `x,y,z` in this order.

In the original `v`, we have `v[2,1,2] == 1.0`. But, by default, `transform` uses the center of the array as origin, so `2,1,2` is relative to center (0,-1,0) i.e. a unit vector in the negative y-axis direction.

The array returned by `transform` has values which are evaluated at `x,y,z` by giving the value of the original `v` at `tfm((x,y,z))` (see `?TransformedArray`).

Specifically, we have `transform(v,tfm)[1,2,2]` is `v[tfm((-1,0,0))]` which is `v[(0,-1,0)]` (because rotating (-1,0,0) counterclockwise is (0,-1,0)) which is `v[2,1,2]` in the uncentered `v` indices. Finally, `v[2,1,2] == 1.0` as was in the output in the question.

Coordinate transformation are always tricky, and it is easy to confuse transformations and their inverse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! @dan-getz. After reading your answer, I went back to read the help of `transform` and `TransformedArray` as well.

Comment: So `transform` actually returns an array that is before the rotation. That is the inverse of the transformation. To obtain the volume after the rotation or any transformation, I need to use the inverse of my transformation. Is that correct?

Comment: `transform` basically takes the standard coordinates of the points in the volume (1:3 x 1:3 x 1:3 in this case), applies `tfm` on them, and looks in `v` for the result. Thus, you get a matrix of the same size, but the `tfm` is applied on the result, so to apply a transform on the source, you need to use the inverse.